# How do I grab URL in Apps Script (.gs) and hand it to a .html script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, url

This is my first question here and I am pretty new to js and html so please excuse if I'm missing something obvious.

Goal: I want to create a script, that creates a Folder in your Google Drive but only if it's not already existing. In that folder it should create a .txt that contains certain information. **After that, I want a new Tab to automatically open the URL of the newly created txt-file.**

If I insert a normal URL in my .html (like "https://www.google.com") it all works perfectly fine. However I'm stuck at the part where the Apps Script hands over the grabbed Url of the newly created file to my html.

Any help is appreciated!

Google Apps Script Code (Code.gs):

```
function myFunction() {

  var FData = "Very important Data"       
  
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Folder");     //create Drive folder if not already created
  var destFolder = destFolder.hasNext() ? 
    destFolder.next() : DriveApp.createFolder("Folder");

  var fileName = "Status.txt";                              //create txt file in that folder and add data to it
  var newFile = destFolder.createFile(fileName,FData);
  var url = newFile.getUrl();                               //?GIVE THIS URL TO openUrl.html?

  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('openUrl').setHeight(100);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Opening...');
}
```

HTML (openUrl.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
     var urlToOpen = url;                     //insert grabbed Url here
     var winRef = window.open(urlToOpen);
     google.script.host.close();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### Google Apps Script side:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var FData = "Very important Data"
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Folder");
  var destFolder = destFolder.hasNext() ? destFolder.next() : DriveApp.createFolder("Folder");
  var fileName = "Status.txt";
  var newFile = destFolder.createFile(fileName, FData);
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('openUrl');
  htmlOutput.url = newFile.getUrl();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput.evaluate().setHeight(100), 'Opening...');
}
```

#### HTML & Javascript side:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
     var urlToOpen = "<?!= url ?>";
     var winRef = window.open(urlToOpen);
     google.script.host.close();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

- When `myFunction()` is run, a dialog is opened by HTML including `url` using HTML template.

#### Reference:

- [HTML Service: Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @Cooper Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience and my poor English skill. From `I tried this and it doesn't seem to work for me.`, unfortunately, I cannot understand the detail of it. This is due to my poor English skill. And, unfortunately, when I tested this, no error occurs and a created file is opened. So, I cannot replicate your situation. But, I would like to support you. So can you provide the detailed flow for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: In my case I could not get the window to open up

Comment: @Cooper Thank you for replying. About `In my case I could not get the window to open up`, unfortunately, I can open a dialog. In your situation, an error might occur. How about this?

Comment: I don't see any console log errors but I captured the url and and I can open it up manually

Comment: @Cooper For example, does that depend on the browser or version of the browser? I testes this using Chrome with v100.0.4896.127.

Comment: I'm using Chrome Version 100.0.4896.127 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I open the chrome dialog but not the window.open(url) tab

Comment: @Cooper Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. In that case, even when a new Spreadsheet is used, does the same situation occurs?

Comment: I'm sorry it turns out that I did not notice that popups were not enabled

Comment: @Cooper Thank you for replying. It's no problem. I think that these discussions will be also useful for other users.

Comment: @Tanaike thank you very much. Your modifications have worked for me! I understand now how to use HTML templates :)

Comment: @bisasamii Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.